# display form with custom property in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to display form with custom property mainly **enctype** in YII.

I have written code in my one of the view file.

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('GxActiveForm', array(
'id' => 'regulation-form',
//'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data',
'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
));
```

but it will render like this

```
<form id="regulation-form" method="post" action="my action">
```

I want result like

```
<form id="regulation-form" method="post" action="my action" enctype='form/multi-part'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `GxActiveForm` extends `CActiveForm`, you need to use the [`htmlOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#htmlOptions-detail) attribute:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('GxActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'regulation-form',
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your form widget as below

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('GxActiveForm', array(
'id' => 'regulation-form',
//'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data',
'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
));
```